# Dojo Mobile filter long item list

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo mobile to build a very simple mobile app which consists of a simple list with more than 500 items with the possibility to filter items.

It's a simple requirement but it seems that it cannot be done with Dojo mobile using existing widgets.

My idea was to use EdgeToEdgeList mixed with LongListMixin and FilteredListMixin but it doesn't work.

How can i accomplish this simple task, have a list with many items that can be filtered with Dojo mobile?

I have to build all from scratch using _TemplatedMixin and the template system? :(

Thank you.

Francesco.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but recently ran into the same situation.  I have found that this does work in version 1.9 of dojo.  I created a widget using both the filter and long list mixin and found them to work together.  If you look at the fiddle, you will see the first 20 ListItems are created, then as you scroll another 20 are added at a time.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView">
 <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props="fixed: 'top'">Heading</h1>
<input  id="accountSearchInput" 
 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SearchBox" 
 type="search" data-dojo-props="queryExpr: '*${0}*'">

<ul id="searchList2" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectStoreList"  
 data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mobile/LongListMixin,dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin"
 class="accountMainList" 
 data-dojo-props='select:"single",store:accountSwitch.childAccounts,itemMap:{accountName:"label", accountId:"id"},filterBoxRef:"accountSearchInput",labelProperty:"accountName"'>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/Lrza3nqs/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this tutorial, even if you don't want to use dojox/app, this can show you how to use a dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList with a dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojox_app/contactsList/

Regards,
Ed

Comment: Thank you for the response Ed, but is it possible to use FilteredListMixin and LongListMixin mixed togheter at the same time in the EdgeToEdgeStoreList or they have to be used separately?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct the tutorial only uses the FilteredListMixin.  I have spent some time this morning trying to get a working test with both FilteredListMixin and LongListMixin and I have not been successful.  I checked with the dojox/mobile developers, and it unfortunately it sounds like they don't work together.